# Change Image in cellForItemAtIndexPath:

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have a problem on this `cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

```
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{           
            NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[[Listname objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]coverURL]];
            NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            shelfcell.bookCover.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];


         });
     });
```

This one  `shelfcell.bookCover.image` can show image but when i use

`if (_checkversionfromBookPathF == 0.1){  shelfcell.bookCover.alpha = 0.5f;}`

`else if(_checkversionfromBookPathF == 1) {  shelfcell.bookCover.alpha = 1.0f; }`

Images will show only `_checkversionfromBookPathF == 1` but will show this one  first`_checkversionfromBookPathF == 0.1`  and then `_checkversionfromBookPathF == 1`

Why image not go `shelfcell.bookCover.alpha = 0.5f;` Please anyone explain me.

Comment: are you saing alpha is not applied to image?or it is not going inside (if block of)_checkversionfromBookPathF ==.1 ?

Comment: It's will go `shelfcell.bookCover.alpha = 0.5f;` first but after loading finish It's go like this `shelfcell.bookCover.alpha = 1.0f;`

Comment: there might be some issue with reusing same cell. Because you are running in another thread, it will take some time to load the image, before it finishes loading the image, this cell might be reused for another indexPath in which shelfcell.bookCover.alpha = 1.0f is executed.

Comment: oh god I don't how to fix but Thank you very much, i'll try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You cant directly compare floats using '==', use < or > symbols not ==.**

there might be some issue with reusing same cell. Because you are running in another thread, it will take some time to load the image, before it finishes loading the image, this cell might be reused for another indexPath in which shelfcell.bookCover.alpha = 1.0f is executed

Solution->

```
NSInteger row=indexPath.row;
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{           
            NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[[Listname objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]coverURL]];
            NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
              //set image if below condition satisfies
              if([tableView indexPathForCell:cell] . row == row){
                  shelfcell.bookCover.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
               }
     });
```

Comment: Thank you very much I'm try this `f (_checkversionfromBookPathF == 1.0f) { if([collectionView indexPathForCell:cell] . row == row){shelfcell.bookCover.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData]; shelfcell.bookCover.alpha = 0.5f;}}`  It's very nice but why I get blur only one image because all `_checkversionfromBookPathF = 1` and have one `_checkversionfromBookPathF =1.1 ` Please explain me.

Comment: you shouldnot  compare floats using ==